# Glob not printing the results

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, operating-system, glob

Ok. I have a list of strings in a file **Jobs.txt** . I need to print the list of text files 
 in **Converted folder** that match the file names with the strings in Jobs.txt file.

When I try to use glob outside the for loop it is working perfectly fine. But when i use the same inside, it is printing empty list.

If I hard code the **'i'** value inside for loop, it is working fine. But it is not printing when **i** is taken from **jobs_in_list** list

```
import glob
import os
jobs_file=open('C:\\Users\\preddy53\\Desktop\\Desktop\\Jobs.txt','r')
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\preddy53\\Desktop\\Jbs\\Converted")
jobs_in_list=jobs_file.readlines()
# i="OP_PU_INS_3568"
# print(glob.glob("*"+i+"*.txt"))
print(len(jobs_in_list))
for i in jobs_in_list:
    print(i)
    print(glob.glob("*"+i+"*.txt"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a space or newline at the end of `i`

Try:

```
print(glob.glob("*"+ i.strip() +"*.txt"))
```